# How to create an item in Sharepoint list and immediately update it using a flow through a PowerApps button?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapp, power-automate, microsoft-flow, powerapps-forms

I have a custom made Power App.

What should happen is: Add some info -> press a button and it should
a) create a new item and b) update one of the fields. ( and then do some other stuff, not relevant for now..)

This is the flow: It gets the highest ***AnalysisNumberCounter***, adds one, padds it and adds 'A#' in front. Finally it appends it to the ***AnalysisNumber*** field.

So for example, if the highest ***AnalysisNumberCounter*** is 1587, then this appends ***A#001588*** to ***AnalysisNumber***

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMyJl.png

The flow on its own works.
But when I call it from inside a PowerApps button it doesn't append the output to the field.

This is the action of the button
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yljG.png

The important thing is that the item must be created and right afterwards updated, while still in the PowerApps, so that some other buttons can work on the newly created ***AnalysisNumber***.

Am I missing an argument or something here?

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, what you are trying to accomplish are:

1. Create a new list item using PowerApps.
2. Trigger a flow using button click in the app.
3. The flow updates the list item.
4. The flow send the data back to PowerApps.

*Step3* is where you are having trouble with. But did you close the form to check if the value is returned in the list?

My suspect is that the list item has been updated, but it remains empty in the PowerApps because the form does not get updated automatically. So you will need *Step4* to keep the app/form open but see the property updated.

I’m not sure if this requirement is possible at all. The closet thing I can find for this idea is this document: [Return data to PowerApps from a flow.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/business-applications-release-notes/april18/microsoft-flow/return-data-powerapps) But it is not quite I’m thinking of.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I have read the link that you gave me. The Set command creates a global variable, while I want to update  a variable from my Sharepoint list. I tried it with Set, but the column that I wanted( AnalysisNumber) was not updated :(

Comment: @VyronB. I don’t think the form gets updated while you hold it open. What if you just stop at Step 3 and close the form, can you see the AnalysisNumber field change?